# Dynkin Diagram roots == $J^{2}$ eigenvalues in $SU(2)$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra

I'm studying Dynkin Diagrams and I've read somewhere that in $SU(2)$ the roots could be given by applying $J^2$ to $|j,m\rangle$ basis, however I must have deleted it and can't find it to read more about it.

So, I wanted to ask is this idea correct? If so, could you recommend any bibliography so I can read about?

P.S.
I might misinterpret it, my apologies if this question is really dumb.

Comment: Do you understand how many roots $SU(2)$ has? I wonder whether you are thinking about *weights* instead.

Comment: Maybe, as I said I lost what I was reading that contained that information, could you explain more about the weights, the roots and how are they connected with Dynkin diagrams and $J^{2}$ eigenvalues, please?

Comment: Sorry, that’s too broad a question. You might find [this reference](http://www.lpthe.jussieu.fr/~zuber/Cours/chap3_12e.pdf) useful. But it is more from the math side than the physics side.

Comment: Just one more questio, the $J^{2}$ eigenvalues give the weights of SU(2)?

Comment: Thank you for the reference, btw

Comment: No, the weights are the eigenvalues of $J_z$. $J^2$ is not an element of the Lie algebra $su(2)$, which consists of linear combinations of $J_i$. $J^2$ lies in a larger algebra called the universal enveloping algebra of $su(2)$, which includes all products of $J_i$.

Comment: There is only one root. $J_3$ eigenvalues are raised/lowered by $J_\pm$.  Your  Casimir invariant $J^2$ reads off the spin $j$ of the representation, as its eigenvalues are $j(j+1)$; they are not weights.

Comment: @CosmasZachos How do you conclude theres only one root?

Comment: @CosmasZachos One *simple* root but two roots, right?

Comment: @RFeynman There is one simple root because the Dynkin diagram has one dot. Dynkin diagrams indicate the geometry of the simple roots.

Comment: Simple, simple. Does the OP understand the ladder? It appears pointless to generalize without  mastery of  what is being generalized.

Comment: I really don't know.... I misinterpreted the concepts of weight and root, as you could see from my post. Can you explain how do you get to that solution, please?

Comment: Yeah, I understand the Ladder Operators!

Comment: You are asking for a discussion of Lie groups, Lie algebras, Cartan subalgebras, raising-lowering operators, Killing forms, roots, simple roots, positive roots, weights, highest weights, Weyl groups, Dynkin diagrams, etc., etc., etc. This is the contents of a semester course on Lie algebra.

Comment: Yeah, maybe its much to ask... I'm sorry. I'm going to take a look to the reference you gave me.

Comment: Are you taking a graduate course, an undergraduate course, or self-studying?

Comment: I'm self-studying to, later on, do project in applications of Dynkin Diagrams in Physics

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system).